# Android Coroutine is getting cancel by it self or OS

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

```
private val mBackgroundThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
private val saveDataScope = CoroutineScope(mBackgroundThread + SupervisorJob())

fun saveData() {
    saveDataScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            saveDataToDB() //gathering data and adding into Database
            delay(duration) // duration is a 10 minutes
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code where I am adding data into database at every 10 mins. This is a part of Foreground service so this will continue calling even if my application is in background or it has been killed.

But I have notices that if this is running for long time then at some point of time this coroutine is getting cancelled by it self and stop calling the recursive call.

Can anyone help to understand why my coroutine is getting cancelled?

Comment: We will ned more info, but it's most likely that there is an issue with the service itself.

Comment: Android will not let you run foreground service forever. Sometimes doze mode can kill even this service

Comment: @bongo what other info you need? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Steyrix Service is running because other tasks are running fine, just coroutine got cancelled.

Comment: Add the code of your `saveDataToDB()` method and the full code of the service itself